# Смена категории для приложения в консоли разработчика гугл после публикации

Tags: android, google-play, mobile-development

Собственно, вопрос - кто уже делал подобные операции и как к этому относится Гугл?
Это делать можно на свой страх и риск или же полностью легальная операция по мнению гугла?
пс. Возникла необходимость сменить категорию, т.к. была выбрана категория с оч сильными конкурентами... похожие приложения размещаются в другой, вот и хотел бы быть выше них с меньшими затратами.